# Parsing HTML with xpath and possible other methods

Tags: php, xpath

I am using xpath with PHP but for some reason none of my queries are working. Curl returns the html for the site so I am thinking it is probably something wrong with the DOM or xpath initialization. Also I am relatively new to xpath so any suggestions on how to clean up future queries would be appreciated as well. In this example I am just looking for the title, but in the future I would like to pull items like shortcut icons and text tags. All approaches and comments are welcome as well as different ways to do what xpath accomplishes more efficiently or accurately. Since xpath cannot always get tags in some extraneous cases I was thinking about having several fallbacks or layers of other methods to get the data. I know most consider it unacceptable to parse html with regular expressions, however could this be a possible fallback method? Mainly what I am asking though is what is causing my code to return nothing.

Thanks in advance to responders.

PHP:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchisake-onna");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$titleQuery = $xpath->query('//title');
//$title = $titleQuery->item(1)->nodeValue;

print_r($titleQuery);

//echo $title;


?>
```

Response:

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

Comment: sidenote: that commented line, it should be `->item(0)` and your code works fine

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about that...

Comment: I am getting DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 1 ) this as response

Comment: Yeah, I changed the the commented line to ->item(0) and it returned the title: Kuchisake-onna - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia. Was just a small mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could always check if you got results from an xpath query.

Sample code:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchisake-onna");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

// check errors before even starting parsing
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
// clear errors from non-well formatted/broken HTML
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($cl);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// query
$titleQuery = $xpath->query('//title');

if($titleQuery->length > 0) {
    // if found at least 1 then continue your logic
    // foreach loops, etc. whatsoever

    $title = $titleQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
else {
    // none found
}
```

With regards to some of queries, etc., of course you can consult on w3c. [Manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). I use this all time, and very useful. It's all laid out in here.